# Platform android already exists. Ionic cordova cannot add platform

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have run into an error when `cordova build`. So I decided to do a `cordova clean` and `cordova build`. But the error persists saying something wrong with aapt. Some answers online said it might be a google.support version problem. So I did `ionic cordova rm android`, and removed my android from my project.

But when I tried to `ionic cordova add android`. It always shows me `Platform android already exists.`. I have been searching online but could not find a similar question.

I tried to delete the platforms folder, and add platform again. Still the same error. But when I reopen that project. `platforms` folder will be added back automatically which this structure inside.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `ionic cordova platform remove android` and check if the syntax run successfully and if the  folder was deleted ,and remember to close all files or folders opened in the same path .
run `ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0` or any other version .

Comment: wow, your method which I had tried before but didnt work. but don't know why, the `ionic cordova platform remove android` command is working now! Thanks!

Comment: :), I could not delete the platform before, because the google-services.json is used by another program. (Which I have no idea). My current approach was to sleep the computer or restart the computer to stop that program from stopping the deletion :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because I had platform/android folder open in android studio
After running `ionic cordova platform remove android` the folder was always there
Just close the project in android studio and run the command from another terminal

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. In my case the solution was detect that process had catch the folder, (adb.exe).

Then I killed the process and I could execute ionic cordova platform rm android, and then add platform again.

If you can't detect the process, you can restar the pc and try again.